# How can I write a script that iterates through a folder and creates new files/file content with given parameters

Tags: linux, xml, bash, unix

I have hundreds of files formatted like :

```
A5566.jar Q1223.jar . . . etc
```

I would like to have a script that takes each .jar file, creates a .xml and .trigger file with the same file name, and also creates a field  within the .xml file that also has that corresponding file name:

```
A5566.xml Q1223.xml . . . etc ,
```

and

```
A5566.trigger Q1223.trigger . . . etc
```

And inside each xml file would be:

```
A5566.xml: “<ID>A5566<ID>”

Q1223.xml: “<ID>Q1223<ID> . . . etc
```

The trigger file contents will be empty:

```
A5566.trigger: “”

Q1223.trigger: “” . . . etc
```

the goal is to have two folders remaining , one with xml files and one with trigger files, after the script has ran.

So far I have :

```
#!/bin/bash

jar_dir=/tmp/jar     # we setup a variable with the directory where to search for jars
xml_dir=/tmp/xml               # same for the output directory for xmls
trigger_dir=/tmp/trigger       # and the trigger directory

# the following creates output directories if they don't exist
# see `man mkdir`
mkdir -p ${xml_dir}
mkdir -p ${trigger_dir}

# we start the for loop through all the files named `*.jar` located in the $jar_dir directory
for f in $(find ${jar_dir} -name "*.jar")
do
        file_id=$(basename -s .jar ${f})   # extract the first part of the file name, excluding .jar
        # echo prints something, \< and \> are escaped characters
        # and the `>` you see just before ${xml_dir} redirects the output of the last command (echo)
        # to the file ${xml_dir}/${file_id}.xml, with the variables replaced
        echo \<id\>${file_id}\</id\> > ${xml_dir}/${file_id}.xml
        touch ${trigger_dir}/${file_id}.trigger   # this one just creates an empty file at ${trigger_dir}/${file_id}.trigger
done
```

I do not really know if I properly ran this script in the specific folder that contains all my jar files (jar), and to have it create two more folders (xml) and (trigger) , containing the newly produced files.

Comment: What is the problem with that script? Looks OK at first glance.

Comment: @daniu I am having trouble running the script in the directory, also with creating folders for xml and trigger files.

Answer (score 1):

`find` is overkill for this task, and won't work in a `for` loop if filenames contain whitespaces. Use globs (instead of `find`)  and parameter expansions (instead of `basename`):

```
#!/bin/bash

jar_dir=/tmp/jar
xml_dir=/tmp/xml
trigger_dir=/tmp/trigger

mkdir -p "$xml_dir" "$trigger_dir"

cd "$jar_dir" || exit
for file in *.jar; do
    id=${file%.jar} # get rid of the extension .jar
    echo "<ID>$id<ID>" > "$xml_dir/$id.xml"
    : > "$trigger_dir/$id.trigger"
done
```

Comment: You can change the `$IFS` variable to make sure spaces does not break your for loop ;-)

Comment: @GrégoireBOUX That would need more work. Globs are much more simpler and more general. They will work even if filenames contain newline characters.

Comment: Would this still be able to create folders: "xml" and "trigger" in the "tmp" directory, where the original "jar" folder is located? thank you for this. @M.NejatAydin

Comment: @Ooka Yes. `mkdir -p "$xml_dir" "$trigger_dir"` does exactly this (perhaps I've misunderstood the question?).

Comment: Okay thank you, I am just new to using the command prompt. So I should create a folder on my desktop called tmp and put my jar file there probably. Then modify the code to be
`jar_dir=C:/user/desktop/tmp/jar`
`xml_dir=C:/user/desktop/tmp/xml`
`trigger_dir=C:/user/desktop/tmp/trigger`
I believe? I am also on a windows system, I would need to download the windows subsystem for linux to be able to run this script If I am correct.